# Is finding data to fit a hypothesis unscientific?

Tags: logic, epistemology, philosophy-of-science, ontology, scientific-method

It seems to me that many people find observations/data in order to fit the hypothesis or to prove the conclusion of their arguments. In one example, one might regard taking a set of lab data and going through them to find the numbers that make the equation work cherry picking. And yet, scientists don't use all data available, but are forced to make decisions about which variables and values to start with. For instance, if a biologist is taking a population sample, how she samples is a choice to find and use some data and disregard others.

Since scientists are forced to choose some data in every experiment, how come some data choice is cherry picking, and other choices are not cherry picking? If all scientists are capable of bias, isn't the very act of having scientists choose data to begin with unscientific?

Answer (score 3):

That action is informally called *cherry-picking* and is motivated by something called *confirmation bias*. Both are inappropriate for use in scientific work but are very commonly used by politicians and unscrupulous scientists to trick nonscientists into accepting falsehoods.

Comment: We gather data to find out if we are on the right track, not in order to prove that we are right. The second type of evidence-and-reasoning is that the lawyers in the criminal court engage in, not what academics ought to be doing.

Answer (score 2):

A basic version of the scientific method is that you form a complete set of competing hypotheses, use them to make a set of predictions that distinguish them all, and then perform the experiment looking for data to eliminate all those hypotheses inconsistent with observation. It should make no difference if you have a favourite hypothesis you're trying to find support for - the method will still eliminate it if it is wrong.

There is a fallacious version of this where you form a hypothesis, make predictions from it, and then go looking for data that fits the prediction, calling that 'confirmation of the hypothesis'. It ignores the fact that very often there are many unmentioned alternative hypotheses that would make the same prediction, and thus are not eliminated. It depends on the classic fallacy called "confirming the consequent", and is profoundly unscientific.

An even worse process is where you form a hypothesis, make predictions, look at the data, and then throw away any data that doesn't fit the preferred hypothesis. The data left is presented as "confirmation". That's called "cherrypicking".

*Looking for data to **test** a hypothesis*, hoping/expecting it will fit, is not itself unscientific - it's what scientists are supposed to do. *Looking for data only to confirm and not contradict a hypothesis* is unscientific, although sadly all too common.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question.

The [logical positivists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_positivism) came up against the same challenge. They believed that all of science could be purged of metaphysics, and that all science could be reduced to objective observations that could be clearly stated. Then a particularly bright positivist came up with a paradox to reject this position, that science could be restricted to observation statements. From WP:

> Carl Hempel became a major critic within the logical positivism movement. Hempel criticized the positivist thesis that empirical knowledge is restricted to Basissätze/Beobachtungssätze/Protokollsätze (basic statements or observation statements or protocol statements). Hempel elucidated the paradox of confirmation.

In fact, the [raven paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raven_paradox) is extremely famous for creating a dilemma for philosophers of science. How does one exactly go about determining evidence of an experiment??? To save you a lot of thinking, the fallout from the paradox is that there are rules that are applied to determine what is and isn't relevant. As all things philosophical, there was a lot of disagreement of what those rules should be. Then came along Quine, one of the most famous philosophers of the 20th century and he put forth some ideas such as [confirmation holism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_holism) and advanced Duhem's underdeterminism and today is attached to the [Duhem-Quine thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhem%E2%80%93Quine_thesis). From WP:

> The Duhem–Quine thesis, also called the Duhem–Quine problem, after Pierre Duhem and Willard Van Orman Quine, is that in science it is impossible to experimentally test a scientific hypothesis in isolation, because an empirical test of the hypothesis requires one or more background assumptions (also called auxiliary assumptions or auxiliary hypotheses): the thesis says that unambiguous scientific falsifications are impossible.

These claims about science circumscribe some truths about science. First, science is not like a deductive proof that mechanically and definitely proves truths about the world. Every attempt to describe how science is done, including Hempel's own [DN model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive-nomological_model), has been shown to have flaws. In fact, this problem of characterizing exactly what science is has a name: the [demarcation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demarcation_problem).

Secondly, one's biases in science are not merely [cognitive biases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_bias) necessarily. In fact, one's biases are tangled up in the holistic nature of one's previous beliefs, an idea called [theory-ladenness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory-ladenness). What you believe science is affects your assumptions in an experiment to begin with. This aspect of science is so strong, that there are philosophers of science who reject that science has much of a methodology at all, [Feyerabend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Feyerabend) being their champion.

Therefore, and a shock to those confidence-mongering know-it-alls who want to claim that there's an objective path to choosing data in experimentation, there simply are a series of rules of thumb that guide a scientist's intuition in the design of an experiment and gathering data. Every scientist has to choose data to fit a hypothesis. But vetting that data should allow for the experiment to be [confirmed, or verified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verificationism), or [falsified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability), or some other rule applied (preferably all of them) if applicable.

**So, to answer your question, strictly speaking ALL scientist find data to fit hypotheses in one form or another. The question is only do they do it well enough to avoid their own biases to an extent that theories can be moved forward with confirmation, verification, falsification, good politics, and so on.** And that's exactly why science generally demands peer review, which according to Daniel Dennett's term [heterophenomenology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterophenomenology), is a form of skepticism that is leveled against the individual's subjective certainty.

Comment: We gather data to find out if we are on the right track, not in order to prove that we are right. The second type of evidence-and-reasoning is that the lawyers in the criminal court engage in, not what academics ought to be doing.

Comment: I thought being on the right tracks was a railroad engineer's job. I don't know that an epistemological distinction exists like you claim,  but I'd be interested in the distinction if you can provide it.